# How to remove a value from array? javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I create an object thus:

```
var savingArray = new Array({doctorId: "something", username: "something", password: "something", givenName: "something", familyName: "something", address: "something", zip:"something", emailAddress: "something", phoneNumber: "something", labs: "something", defaultLab: "something"});
```

Now i wish to remove every value of objects...I would like to end up with savingArray such that:

```
savingArray == ({doctorId: "", username: "", password: "", givenName: "", familyName: "", address: "", zip:"", emailAddress: "", phoneNumber: "", labs: {}, defaultLab: ""});
```

So all i want is to change all values to "" dinamicaly..

savingArray has never the same object so a can't do like this:

```
savingArray[0].doctorId = "";
```

Comment: Fy, it's cleaner to use `[...]` instead of `new Array(...)` to create an array. And in your second code block the `()` should be `[]`.

Comment: Why would the `labs` property be an empty object, when all other properties are empty strings?

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: You do realize you're creating an array with just one entry, right? And that that *entry* is an object with the various keys on it? Do you at some point have other entries in the array or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < savingArray.length; i++) {
    var obj = savingArray[i];
    for(var key in obj) {
        obj[key] = '';
    }
}
```

Or since you are using jQuery you an also use its `$.each()` function to iterate:

```
$.each(savingArray, function(i, obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        obj[key] = '';
    });
});
```

In case something modified `Object.prototype` (e.g. added methods to it - something that usually shouldn't be done) you'd need to add an `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))` check and only set the value if that check succeeds.

Comment: FWIW `$.each()` doesn't use `.hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: True. But it's most likely not necessary here anyway.

Comment: Yup - I don't use it anymore in my own code.  People still use it cos Crockford said so, but unless you've got code that futzes with `Object.prototype` it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
savingArray.forEach( function( el ) {
    Object.keys( el ).forEach( function( key ) {
        el[ key ] = '';
    });
});
```

Self-explaining code using `forEach` and `Object.keys`. This won't work in IE6/7/8 of course.

Comment: eek!  If you're assuming ES5 you should be using `.forEach()`, not `.map()` - the latter is for use when you're _returning_ a new array.

Comment: I *am* returning an new array :) It isn't necessary, but both ways work.

Comment: @Alnitak I added a forEach way just for you :-)

Comment: @Alnitak uh, I confused this with "replaces the current array", edited with the foreach only :)

Comment: Your first code doesn't work - it does indeed modify the elements in place, but it _also_ returns a new array of arrays which is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Is that you are looking for?

```
for (var i = 0; i < savingArray.length; i++) {
    for (var key in savingArray[i]) {
        if (savingArray[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
            savingArray[i][key] = "";
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NfBqn/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(savingArray, function(index, obj) {
  $.each(obj, function(k, val) {
     obj[k] = "";
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Mf9jL/1/)**

Comment: As you already have `obj`, I'd use `obj[k] = "";` rather than `savingArray[index][k] = "";`. Save the unnecessary lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of a JavaScript object can be treated as a key value pair and it's possible to iterate over the object so what you need to do is first iterate over the objects in the array

```
for(var i = 0;i < savingArray.length; i++)  { ... }
```

and then iterate over the properties of each object. However you also want to test the relation between the property and the object. Putting it all together you end up with code like this:

```
var i,prop,current;
//iterate over the objects in the array
for(i = 0;i<savingArray.length);i++){
  current = savingArray[i];
  //iterate over all the properties of the object
  for(prop in current){
     //test the relationship of the property and the object
     if(current.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        //assign the empty string to the property
        current[prop] = "";
     } 
  }
}
```

or in a jQuery version

```
$.each(savingArray, function(i, obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
           obj[key] = '';
        }
    });
});
```

I expect the previous to be more performant than the jQuery but find the jQuery a little easier to read due to being more condensed

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jQuery, use it for looping arrays and objects also:

```
$.each(savingArray, function(i, item){
  $.each(item, function(key){
    item[key] = "";
  });
});
```